# ACF multi taxonomy on filterable gallery

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, multi-taxonomy-query

I created a filterable gallery with ACF. My problem is that when I add a project to which I add several taxonomies, in my gallery I have the project as many times as I have added taxonomies. Apart from that, I would like the project to appear only once in the gallery but to appear in all the filters where the taxonomy is selected.[image]

```
<div id="filters" class="col-3">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li data-filter="all" class="filter active">Tous les projets</li>
        <?php
        // 1. On définit les argument pour définir ce que l'on souhaite récupérer
        $args = array (
                'post_type' => 'projet'
        );

        $terms_id = [];
        // 2. On execute la WP query
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // 3. On lance la boucle
        if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        
        $categories_du_projet = get_field( 'categories_du_projet' );     
        
        if ( $categories_du_projet ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( $categories_du_projet as $term ) : 
                if (!in_array($term->term_id, $terms_id)) :
                array_push($terms_id, $term->term_id); 
            ?>
            <li data-filter="<?= esc_html( $term->slug ); ?>" class="filter"><?= esc_html( $term->name ); ?></li>
            
        <?php endif; endforeach; endif; endwhile; endif;
        // 4. On réinitialise la requete principale
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="elements" class="col-9">
    <?php
        // 1. On définit les argument pour définir ce que l'on souhaite récupérer
        $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'projet'
        );
        // 2. On execute la WP query
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // 3. On lance la boucle
        if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        $categories_du_projet = get_field( 'categories_du_projet' );
        $image_du_projet = get_field( 'image_du_projet' );
        $titre_du_projet = get_field( 'titre_du_projet' ); 
        $titre_du_projet = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($titre_du_projet));

        $trigger_ID = 'trigger_' . $arr_posts->current_post . '_' . get_the_ID();
        $modal_ID = 'modal_' . $arr_posts->current_post . '_' . get_the_ID();
        $close_ID = 'close_' . $arr_posts->current_post . '_' . get_the_ID();
        $image_ID = 'grandeImage_' . $arr_posts->current_post . '_' . get_the_ID();

        $images = acf_photo_gallery('galerie_du_projet', $post->ID);

        if ( $categories_du_projet ) :
            foreach ( $categories_du_projet as $term ) :
                if ( $image_du_projet ) :
                ?>
                    <div class="<?= esc_html( $term->slug ); ?>">
                        <figure class="trigger" id="<?php echo $trigger_ID ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_du_projet['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_du_projet['alt'] ); ?>" />
                            <figcaption><?php the_field( 'titre_du_projet' ); ?></figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        
                <div class="modal" id="<?= $modal_ID ?>">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close-button" id="<?= $close_ID ?>">&times;</span>
                        <h2><?= get_field( 'titre_du_projet' );  ?></h2>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="image">
                                <?php $image_du_projet = get_field( 'image_du_projet' ); ?>
                                <?php if ( $image_du_projet ) : ?>
                                    <img class="<?= $image_ID; ?>" src="<?= esc_url( $image_du_projet['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?= esc_attr( $image_du_projet['alt'] ); ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <img class="grandeImage" />
        
                                <div class="row" id="gallery-full"> 
                                    <?php
                                        //Check if return array has anything in it
                                        if( count($images) ):
                                            //Cool, we got some data so now let's loop over it
                                            foreach($images as $image):
                                                $id = $image['id']; // The attachment id of the media
                                                $title = $image['title']; //The title
                                                $caption= $image['caption']; //The caption
                                                $full_image_url = $image['full_image_url']; //Full size image url
                                                    //Resized size to 262px width by 160px height image url
                                                $thumbnail_image_url= $image['thumbnail_image_url']; //Get the thumbnail size image url 150px by 150px
                                                $url= $image['url']; //Goto any link when clicked
                                                $target= $image['target']; //Open normal or new tab
                                                $alt = get_field('photo_gallery_alt', $id); //Get the alt which is a extra field (See below how to add extra fields)
                                                $class = get_field('photo_gallery_class', $id); //Get the class which is a extra field (See below how to add extra fields)
                                    ?>
                                        
                                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                            <img id="image_<?= $id; ?>" src="<?= $full_image_url; ?>" alt="<?= $title; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        
                            <div class="description">
                                <h3>Description</h3>
                                <p><?php the_field('description_du_projet'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

All I want is just no duplicate pictures on "all project" just one picture, not one per taxonomies.
If anyone can help me please... Too much time on it and I found nothing to help me.

[image]
This is my var_dump($term) and on this 3 pictures only one can display the modal.
I want on All project display just one picture and when I choose one of the 3 filters, can click on it and display the modal

Comment: Technically you should be asking ACF for assistance with this because their plugin may be doing things a bit different than WordPress would natively.  However, your best approach would be to first collect all of the IDs into a single array, then run `array_unique()` over your array to strip out duplicate IDs, then start your output process.

Comment: I tried to put the id in an array but the problem is that each generated image has only one taxonomy, suddenly it only shows me the first image but not the others

Comment: Ah, you're putting the taxonomies into the array, instead put the returned image IDs into the array and then run your the `array_unique()` and `foreach` loop on the result.  We know you're getting all of the images and some of them are duplicates, so instead of cycling through everything that's returned and outputting each one, first just add them all to an array.

Comment: You want to gather the image ids into an array from your `$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );`.  So in your `while()` instead of running the entire output process, just gather up all the IDs.  Then run a separate `foreach()` to run your output after you've removed duplicates.  I can try to write it out for you after I finish a couple of calls.

Comment: Yes please, but take your time ;)

Comment: I think something like this, but the ACF use makes it a bit harder for me to understand because I'm not that familiar with it:  `$image_array();
            foreach ( $categories_du_projet as $term ) :
                if ( $image_du_projet ) :
                    $image_array[] = $image_du_projet;
                endif;
            endforeach;
            foreach( $image_array as $image_article ) :`

From there you'd want to then adjust your output to use `$image_article` instead of `$image_du_project`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Wow, that looks horrible...  I'll add it as an answer instead so it's formatted nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all of the image IDs and then cycling through them and outputting each one, you would first collect them into a single array and then use `array_unique()` to remove the duplicates.

```
        if( $categories_du_projet ) :
            $image_array();
            foreach( $categories_du_projet as $term ) :
                if( $image_du_projet ) :
                    $image_array[] = $image_du_projet;
                endif;
            endforeach;
            $image_array = array_unique( $image_array );
            foreach( $image_array as $image_article ) :
                //now run your output method using $image_article rather than $image_du_projet
                //you'll probably have to change how you're obtaining things like the URL, ALT, etc.
            endforeach;
        endif;
```

What I'm not sure of is `$image_du_projet = get_field( 'image_du_projet' );` and what that actually gets.  I'm assuming it's the ID of the image.  If that's wrong you'll probably need to modify things a bit.

Perhaps then you'd need to add this:

```
$image_du_projet_id = $image_du_projet['ID'];
$image_array[] = $image_du_projet_id;
```

Sorry I can't give a definitive answer in that regard but there's no way for me to really test it as I don't have ACF or those fields configured anywhere.

Comment: I var_dump $image_array and I see nothing about the category. You code work but I think ACF create one taxonomy per post even if it's a single post :/ 
I mail ACF and wait for an answer =) Thanks to your help and tell you if i find a solution ^^